# Compare different loadings of a SEM model across different datasets

Tags: multivariate-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan, invariance

I am interested in knowing if the same phenotypic structure holds across six different datasets. First, I have done six different multivariate analyses for my six different datasets (using MCMCglmm). For each resulting multivariate analysis, I obtained the correlation matrices (as I have repeated measures for different individuals). Then, I used these matrices as an input to perform six different structural equation modeling (same model across datasets). From this, I obtained the factor loading for each path for each dataset (using lavaan). Now I am interested in comparing if the loadings of each SEM across datasets are similar. I have tried to do an invariance model to compare datasets but have not figured out the way to include each of the correlation matrices (as they test the among-individual level) for each of the datasets.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `list()` of covariance matrices (and a vector of corresponding sample sizes) to `lavaan()` instead of raw `data=`.

https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/cov.html (see bottom of page)

Also see the `sample.cov=` and `sample.nobs=` descriptions on the `?lavaan` help page.  Then you can test invariance across groups:

https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/groups.html

However, those tests assume you variables have the same scale (units of measurement) across groups.  Unstandardized covariance matrices should be analyzed, rather than standardized covariance matrices (i.e., correlation matrices).

http://statpower.net/Content/319SEM/Reading/Cudeck89.pdf

If a syntax example helps:

```
data(HolzingerSwineford1939, package = "lavaan")
HS123 <- HolzingerSwineford1939[paste0("x",1:3)] # save x1-x3

## save each school's covariance matrix
(Pcov  <- cov(HS123[ HolzingerSwineford1939$school == "Pasteur" , ]))
(GWcov <- cov(HS123[ HolzingerSwineford1939$school == "Grant-White" , ]))

## store group-specific information in lists
(covList <- list(Pasteur = Pcov, `Grant-White` = GWcov))
(Ns <- table(HolzingerSwineford1939$school))

## specify and fit a multigroup CFA
mod.config <- ' visual =~ c(L1.p, L1.gw)*x1 + c(L2.p, L2.gw)*x2 + c(L3.p, L3.gw)*x3 '
fit.config <- cfa(mod.config, sample.cov = covList, sample.nobs = Ns)
summary(fit.config)
```

Comment: Thank you Terrence! But then I have two questions: (a) is this type of approach sensitive to different sample sizes? and (b) when you get the summary how can you be sure that the loadings for each path indeed differ or not?

Comment: (a) Yes, smaller groups provide less information than larger groups (whether balanced or not), which means less power to discover differences.  (b)  You would fit a metric-invariance model with equal loadings (set labels equal by deleting the `.p` and `.gw` suffixes), and use `lavTestLRT()` to compare that model to `fit.config`.  Find details in any literature about testing measurement invariance using CFA.